# Element offsets and covered text in dom4j

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

We need to process an XML file which contains PCDATA elements like the following:

```
<corpus id="c01">
  <text id="t01>
    <sentence id="s01">Mary <instance id="i01">had</instance> a <instance id="i02">lamb</instance>.</sentence>
    <sentence id="s02">...</sentence>
    ...
  </text>
  ...
</corpus>
```

For each <sentence> of each <text>, we need to populate a data structure containing the sentence ID and the full text covered by the sentence.  Then for each <instance>, we need to populate a data structure containing the instance ID and its start and end position within the sentence.  (We don't care whether or not the white space is normalized.)

So for the above example, we basically need the following:

```
s.id = "s01"
s.text = "Mary had a lamb."
i1.id = "i01"
i1.start = 6
i1.end = 8
i2.id = "i02"
i2.start = 12
i2.end = 15
```

Is there any way of doing this with dom4j?  The Element.getText() method skips over the text of child elements, and I don't see any methods which give the offset of an element within another.  If dom4j isn't appropriate for this task, what's a better tool?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly doable, but requires a little work. You could create a Visitor that keeps track of where it is in the tree and accumulates the text and instance offsets as it progresses. However, that solution could just as well be implemented by a SAX handler directly, which would be a lot faster.

This should give something to start with:

```
public class Main extends DefaultHandler {

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
boolean collecting = false;
int ic = 0;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("sentence")) {
        System.out.printf("s.id=%s\n", attributes.getValue("id"));
        collecting = true;
        buf.setLength(0);
        ic = 0;
    } else if (localName.equals("instance")) {
        ++ic;
        System.out.printf("i%d.id=%s\n", ic, attributes.getValue("id"));
        System.out.printf("i%d.start=%s\n", ic, buf.length());
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("sentence")) {
        collecting = false;
        System.out.printf("s.text=%s\n", buf.toString());
    } else if (localName.equals("instance")) {
        System.out.printf("i%d.end=%s\n", ic, buf.length());
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (collecting) {
        buf.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SAXParserFactory f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    f.setNamespaceAware(true);
    f.newSAXParser().parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("data.xml"),
            new Main());
}
}
```